# Is there a command line Bitcoin CPU miner for Windows?

Tags: windows, cpu-mining, mining-software

Is there a Bitcoin miner that I can run using the command line on Windows? I want a CPU miner, not a GPU miner.

Comment: You do understand that at this difficulty level, you will not recoup your power costs from bitcoin mining? This link provides an idea of what hash rates you'll get from CPU and GPU mining
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison I wouldn't recommend it even if the power is free. It just isn't worth the wear and tear on your CPU.

Comment: `bitcoin-cli -rpcconnect=127.0.0.1 generate 1`

Answer (score 7):

You can install the standard Bitcoin-QT client, navigate to

```
\Program Files (x86)\bitcoin\daemon\
```

and then run

```
bitcoind -gen=1
```

However this isn't recommended except on the Test network because it is next to impossible to generate any coins this way on the production network.

Answer (score 2):

One of the best for both LiteCoins and BTC is

CGminer

It supports both Linux & Windows

Download from here

https://github.com/ycros/cgminer/downloads

You can get complete instructions from

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=28402.0

Or just check the readme including in the zip

It Supports FGPA GPU and GPU for BTC & GPU for LiteCoins..there is extensive tuning instructions as part of teh community so if you want to get the most bang for your $$ then this is the one :D

Comment: Does the litecoin cgminer use IRC?  Also do you know if cgminer works with Butterfly Labs FPGA for *litecoin*?  I thought lightcoin was made to resist FPGA/GPU optimizations

Comment: ckolivas has got it working for GPU with TacoTime (big Litecoinminer) using both it & reaper for GPU Litecoin mining with cgminer being the most stable i.e 9 days and no probs with cgminer...FGPA wont work as the code is specific for BTC ..my bad should have stated FGPA only for BTC..have edited answer to suit :D

Comment: It Uses/Supports IRC as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

[This client](http://ufasoft.com/coin/) includes a command-line miner which supports CPU mining (and GPU, should you have one available).

But unless you're mining in a pool, you're not going to get any benefit from CPU mining. And even with a pool, you'll get very little.