# The Legit & Safe—Windows Command Line Miner

Tags: mining-pools, client, cpu-mining

I read over the "[Is there a command line Bitcoin CPU miner for Windows?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5899/is-there-a-command-line-bitcoin-cpu-miner-for-windows)" post and **GCMiner** looked promising for a Windows command line scriptable solution that allows pool mining.

I tried downloading the **GCMiner** client right from GitHub links from *Windows* via the *Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer* web browsers and all of them say something is ***unsafe*** and prevents me from downloading the CLI tool. I tried to download from *Linux Mint* via the *Firefox* web browser from the GitHub links and got the same unsuccessful result.

### Question

Is there a safe Windows client that is command line that I can use to mine in a pool such as SlushPool for CPU mining I suppose?

- I'm setting this up to play with and become familiar with the pool management side more than the configuration so I'm not worried about CPU being ineffienct over GPU.
- If I can safely download **CGMiner** to start playing with it on Windows that'd even work.

**Note:** I'd prefer to use a pool like **SlushPool** where I can put in my unique username and whatever miner names I define only. I don't want a client that requires an email address in the logic to mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no official CGMiner binaries being distributed anymore specifically because of this problem. You will need to download the source code and compile it yourself. Instructions for doing that are available [here](https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer/blob/master/windows-build.txt).

---

The reason that CGMiner is flagged as Unsafe is due to Anti-Virus software and malware that use CGMiner. Anti-Virus have performed analyses of the CGMiner and determined it to be a cryptocurrency mining software - which it is. Unfortunately, a lot of malware are also capable of mining cryptocurrencies once they infect someone's computer, so AVs have taken to flagging everything that can mine cryptocurrencies as unsafe. This then reaches the browsers which do the same.